# Observing files loaded with F12, the IE debugger?

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, browser, ie-developer-tools

I'm trying to do some IE8 debugging with F12, the Windows debugger.

How can I check which scripts, stylesheets etc have loaded, with their response codes, etc?

In other words, what's the F12 equivalent of the 'Network' tab in Chrome Developer Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE9 there is a Network tab in F12 tools, however I don't think this is available in IE8. You'll have to either run IE9 in IE8 mode or use a third party tool like [IETester](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ietester&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.my-debugbar.com%2Fwiki%2FIETester%2FHomePage&ei=RNiNT7arEoSbtwfx4KDeCw&usg=AFQjCNF_tDLTJQgeAKXrbUKXwWtqRIiI8g).